# jQuery UI Datepicker Style Broken

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, uidatepicker

I have a jQuery UI Datepicker object popping up when I click inside a textbox. Here is the HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="label-td"><label for="dateOpen_add">Date Opened</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="dateOpen_add" name="dateOpen_add" maxlength="10" size="10" /></td>
</tr>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('#dateOpen_add').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    date: $('#dateOpen_add').val(),
    current: $('#dateOpen_add').val(),
    starts: 1,
    position: 'bottom',
    onBeforeShow: function(){
            $('#dateOpen_add').setDate($('#dateOpen_add').val(), true);
    },
    onChange: function(formated, dates){
            $('#dateOpen_add').val(formated);
    }
});
```

For some reason, the datepicker shows up like this when I click in the `dateOpen_add` textbox:

[image: Datepicker Messed Up]

Also, here is a link to the problem in action: [LINK](http://xtracktech.com/xtrack/fasttrack/test-page.php)

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Sorry. Check your jQuery UI stylesheet(s)? Seems like a "personal" problem.

Comment: I was afraid it might be a "personal" problem. I didn't touch anything in the UI stylesheet so I'm not sure what is causing this annoying problem. I guess I can download a new UI stylesheet and try that to see if it gets rid of the problem. At least I'll narrow it down a bit.

Comment: Do you have a live link that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: Also, if you have Chrome or Firefox with Firebug, you could inspect these elements to determine where/how the overrides are originating.

Comment: Here is [a link](http://xtracktech.com/xtrack/fasttrack/test-page.php) to an example of the problem.

Comment: Did you try `Inspect Element`? I find `http://xtracktech.com/xtrack/fasttrack/css/fasttrack-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css`, which seems to be where the "custom" stylesheet gives the black/white look. This seems "self-inflicted". Try the jQuery ThemeRoller: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your style #selected-folders-table td, th in Global.css (line 97 & 125) is setting the min-width of ALL th elements to 125px

You can rewrite this css selector to #selected-subfolders-table td, #selected-subfolders-table th {...} to make the selector more specific and fix the bug